# Streaming UDP protocol on Android

Tags: video, streaming

I'm trying to stream satellite TV from my desktop PC to my Android phone.

I'm using [DVB Dream](http://www.dvbdream.org/), the software is transmitting on `udp://@`. I've already tried downloading VLC for Android, but it seems like UDP streaming is not supported.

Do you have any idea that could help me solve this riddle?

Comment: If the source is your desktop PC I assume that your local network will not have any bandwidth problems - hence you will not face packet loss. Therefore using UDP will not get you any advantage. Have you tried to use TCP for streaming instead?

Comment: dvbdream transmits only on udp

Comment: i would like to do this, vlc on pc works but not android...

Answer (score 2):

[UDP](http://ivoire.dinauz.org/blog/index.php?post/2011/02/02/VLC-on-Android#c104) streaming in [VLC on android](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html) is [supported](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=91423). UDP is not a good way to stream over wifi. You will get a lot of packet loss. If you can't change that in DVB Dream, there are other applications (like TVersity for example) that can stream to android (and other devices) with no problems (or little problems) and they even transcode the video so it is in a format that is "native" to the device.